# How main thread runs before this thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have the following code:

```
    public class Derived implements Runnable {
        private int num;

        public synchronized void setA(int num) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            System.out.println("Setting value " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            this.num = num;
        }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("In run: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        setA(20);
    }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Derived obj = new Derived();
            Thread t1 = new Thread(obj);
            t1.start();
            obj.setA(32);
        }
    }
```

This prints:

```
In run: Thread-0
Setting value main
Setting value Thread-0
```

My question is if I started the thread 't1' first, and it entered the run method as the output shows, how come main thread was able to call setA before 't1' if the object was locked by t1? (or even before getting a lock on 'obj' main was able to get a lock) Is it just the scheduler or am I thinking it wrong?

Comment: There are no guarantees about ordering with threads unless you take explicit steps to synchronize them.  That's the whole point of threads, they are asynchronous.

Comment: The main thread is already up and running when this code is called. Your other thread will take just a little time to get constructed and running, and so I'm not surprised at the result that you're seeing. Plus what @JimGarrison stated above.

Comment: Your code also should not compile -- you've a Runnable with no `run()` method.

Comment: @JimGarrison : So it is just the scheduler right? What I was trying to do is if a thread has acquired a lock, no other thread would enter setA

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks for the answer. I added the run

Comment: Your error is in assuming when an object acquires the lock.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes that is right. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how come main thread was able to call setA before 't1' if the object was locked by t1?

The whole point of using multiple threads is to allow code in each thread to run independently.  The `Thread.start()` (or any method) is not instantaneous.  It take time and while your thread is starting, you can run code in your current thread, in fact it can run to completion before your background thread even starts.

> Is it just the scheduler

That is part of it. But it's also the fact that starting a Thread isn't free and takes a non-trivial amount of time.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        new Thread(() -> System.out.println("Thread took " +
                (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1e6 + " ms to start"))
                .start();
    }
}
```

I have a fast machine but when I run this program to start the first thread takes a while.

```
Thread took 44.695419 ms to start
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Peter.Great explanation. What I was trying was when a thread enters a synchronized method, no other thread can enter any synchronized methods of the object even if I make the thread sleep. Am I right? Also can another thread enter a non-synchronized which is accessing a class data?

Comment: @Vwin correct about synchronized and sleep, note: if you wait() instead, another thread can obtain the lock. Any number of thread can run a method if isn't not synchronized.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the help

Comment: The method being synchronized only means that whoever gets in first prevents the second client from running for a bit. It doesn't guarantee who gets in first.